# how to place a sprite at touch position

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.x

I follow the lecture of this website: 
[website](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/10/03/Cocos2d-x-Tutorial-Series-Handling-Touch-and-Mouse-Input.aspx)
My code is same as first part of the website.But the position where the label placed in is uppon the place I clicked at.
Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong code is at

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
auto director = Director::getInstance();
auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
if(!glview) {
    glview = GLViewImpl::create("Hello World");
    glview->setFrameSize(640, 480);
    director->setOpenGLView(glview);
}

auto scene = HelloWorld::createScene();
director->runWithScene(scene);

return true;
}
```

the code line;

```
glview->setFrameSize(640, 480);
```

setFrameSizw width diffrent size of defalut window size;